# How to make correct loop of JSON in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've got a problem with making a correct loop in React. I want to fetch data from JSON to don't repeat components. I tried to make two loops and then two maps, but everything was in bad order. The other problem is that `"description"` is also an array that's why I'm not able to deal with it

JSON:

```js
{
  "oswiecim": [
    {
      "header": "Oświęcim Zasole",
      "description": [
        "Rejon ulic św Maksymiliana Kolbego",
        "i Stanisławy Leszczyńskiej"
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Oświęcim Zasole",
      "description": [
        "Rejon ulic Więźniów Oświęcimia",
        "Obozowej, Polnej i Legionów"
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Stare Miasto",
      "description": [
        "Rejon Rynku i Placu ks. Jana Skarbka oraz ",
        "ulic Zamkowej i Władysława Jagiełły"
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Stare Miasto",
      "description": [
        "Cmentarz Parafialny oraz rejon",
        "ul. Wysokie Brzegi."
      ]
    },
    {
      "header": "Osiedle Chemików",
      "description": [
        "Największa pod względem liczby ludności",
        "dzielnica Oświęcimia"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

React:

```js
import '../../styles/selection/Selection.scss'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Selection = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const getData = async () => {
        await fetch('https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.b95a27020e1c45e9b3a7c95a74fc5d49', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData(data)

            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])

    const headers = []
    const descriptions = []
    for (const item of data.oswiecim) {
        headers.push(item.header)

        descriptions.push(item.description)

    }



    return (
            <div className="selection">
                    {headers.map(item => (
                        <h1>{item}</h1>
                    ))}
                  {descriptions.map(item => (
                    item.map(elem => (
                        <p>{elem}</p>
                    ))
                ))}
            </div>
    );
}

export default Selection;
```

The result should look like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to separate `header` and `description` in two different variables.

So try something like this:-

```
return (
    <div className="selection">
      {data.oswiecim?.map((item) => (
        <>
          <h1>{item.header}</h1>
          {item.description?.map((description) => (
            <p>{description}</p>
          ))}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-roentgen-uw9kz)

Comment: I really appreciate your response, it helped me a lot :) Can I ask you what's the reason for the question mark right here: `{data.oswiecim?.map()}`?

Comment: That stands for optional chaining. If your api does not return `oswiecim` in your data then by using this chaining you can prevent page break or error in future. You can find more info about optional chaing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `setData(data);` with following. It will just give the array you need to iterate,

```
setData(data.oswiecim);
```

Remove the following code,

```
const headers = []
    const descriptions = []
    for (const item of data.oswiecim) {
        headers.push(item.header)

        descriptions.push(item.description)

    }
```

Replace return statement with following,

```
<div className="selection">
    {data &&
        data.map(item => (
            <>
                <div>{item.header}</div>
                {item.description &&
                    item.description.map(descriptionItem => <p>{descriptionItem}</p>)}
            </>
        ))}
</div>
```

Comment: @Stairss, check this out!

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I wanted :)